# Existence of module with periodic resolution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a Gorenstein local ring. Does there always exist a module $M$ having eventually periodic minimal free resolution?

Any reference is also appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

This is not true. For example, let $k$ be a field and let $R$ be the finite dimensional Gorenstein $k$-algebra $k[u, v, w]/(uw − v^2, u^2, uv, vw, w^2)$. Then all finitely generated modules are either projective or their minimal projective resolutions have exponential growth. The radical layers of this algebra have dimensions $1$, $3$, $1$. See for example my paper, "Resolutions over symmetric algebras with radical cube zero," J Algebra 320 (2008), 48-56. I'm sure there must be other good references too.

On the other hand, it is true for a local complete intersection. A relevant reference is "Homological algebra on a complete intersection, with an application to group representations," by David Eisenbud, TAMS 260 (1980).